# Tweaks for 3ware raid

Tags: hardware-raid

Does applying these tweaks to the sdb raid harm any data that is already on the array?

```
echo 64 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/max_sectors_kb
echo 512 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/nr_requests
echo deadline > /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
echo 20 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
echo 60 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
blockdev --setra 16384 /dev/sdb
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those changes are non-destructive.